# Download Azure Blob from Website of WebApp with AAD Identity logged in with RoleBased IAM access

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

Azure Active Directory B2C tenant:

- Group is configured, users are assigned to group
- .net core 5 WebApp is configured as registered application

Azure StorageV2:

- public availability, CORS is configured correctly
- container is NOT public available, IAM is configured for group access

.net core 5 WebApp with Identity Framework:

- User Login is working, Identity cookie is present
- I have the user's groups available via Microsoft Graph

**Now** - within a razor page - I am generating some code to let the user download stuff:

```
<tr><td><img crossorigin="use-credentials" src="@Model.ImagesServiceUri/${image.id}"></img> 
</td></tr>
```

when loading the page in browser client this returns:
404 - resource does not exist (like it always does if you do not have access rights)

What must be done to download blob with the IAM rights of the already to the webapp logged in user?

- is any more configuration to the active directory required?
- is any more configuration to the storage required
- is there any other thing in azure to configure?
- pure client side - is there any way to use the present local cookie to identify towards the azure storage? crossorigin="use-credentials" is adding the right headers but not the right id token
- is there a way in the webapp to add a token to the url and add that token to the generated URL?

Comment: Could you please tell me which role you have assigned to the group?

Comment: Besides could you please provide a simple sample? Let us do a test.